# How can i combine and pull apart rows of a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame of users information like Name, Mail, Birthday, Genre... but the dataframe have duplicate users with important different info in both rows. Also the problem that there are different users with the same Name. For example:

Original Dataframe

```
     Name Mail          Birthday Genre Subscription Age  Comments
0    A    A@gmail.com   1-1-1990 M     Y            33   -
1    B    None          NaT      F     N            NaN  -
2    C    C@gmail.com   1-1-1985 M     Y            38   -
3    D    None          1-1-1980 I     N            43   - 
4    B    None          1-1-1995 I     N            27   -
5    D    D@gmail.com   NaT      M     Y            NaN  -
6    B    B@gmail.com   NaT      I     Y            NaN  -
7    C    C2@gmail.com  1-1-1970 F     N            53   -
```

And I want something like that:

```
     Name Mail          Birthday Genre Subscription Age Comments
0    A    A@gmail.com   1-1-1990 M     Y            33  -
1    B    B@gmail.com   1-1-1995 F     Y            27  -
2    C    C@gmail.com   1-1-1985 M     Y            38  -
3    D    D@gmail.com   1-1-1980 M     Y            43  -
4    C2   C2@gmail.com  1-1-1970 F     N            53  -
```

It's possible to for example group by name and combine the rows keeping all the information in one row, and if in both rows in a column have the same value keep it. And also if 2 rows of different values have the same name, create a row for the other user with the new name.

for example an intermediate df:

```
     Name Mail            Birthday   Genre Subscription Age   Comments
0    A    A@gmail.com     1-1-1990   M     Y            33    -
1    B    B@gmail.com     1-1-1995   F     Y            27    -
2    C    [C@gmail.com,   [1-1-1985, [M,   [Y,          [38,  [-,
           C2@gmail.com]   1-1-1970]  F]    N]           53]   -]
3    D    D@gmail.com     1-1-1980   M     Y            43    -
```

I tried with groupby function, or with join function but did not work correctly for me.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the code you wrote to attempt to achieve this output? So we can build on your current attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine values with replace values per folumnc for exclude with aggregate by all columns without `Name` by custom function with reusing variable by walrus operator `:=` with convert ene element lists to scalars and empty lists after remove missing values and duplicates to `NaN`s:

```
f = lambda x: y if (len(y:=list(dict.fromkeys(x.dropna()))) > 1) 
                else y[0] 
                if len(y) != 0 
                else np.nan

df = (df.replace({'Mail':{'None':np.nan},
                  'Birthday':{'NaT':np.nan},
                  'Genre':{'I':np.nan}, 
                  'Subscription':{'N':np.nan}})
        .set_index('Name')
        .groupby('Name')
        .agg(f))
print (df)
                             Mail              Birthday   Genre Subscription  \
Name                                                                           
A                     A@gmail.com              1-1-1990       M            Y   
B                     B@gmail.com              1-1-1995       F            Y   
C     [C@gmail.com, C2@gmail.com]  [1-1-1985, 1-1-1970]  [M, F]            Y   
D                     D@gmail.com              1-1-1980       M            Y   

               Age Comments  
Name                         
A             33.0        -  
B             27.0        -  
C     [38.0, 53.0]        -  
D             43.0        -
```