# clean and split dataframe rows in different rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame of users information like Name as index, Mail, Birthday, Genre, User, Age... but the dataframe have some lists in different values, for example:

```
Name |      Mail      |  Birthday  | Genre | User | Subscription | Age | Comments
 A   |  A@gmail.com   | [1-1-1990, |  [M,  | [Z,  |    Y         | [33,|  -
     |                |  1-1-2000, |   F]  |  A]  |              |  23,|
     |                |  1-1-1998] |       |      |              |  25]|
 B   |  B@gmail.com   | [1-1-1970, |  F    |  B   |   [Y,        | [53,|  -
     |                |  13-2-1998]|       |      |    N]        |  24]|
 C   | [C@gmail.com,  | [1-1-1985, | [M,   |  C   |   [Y,        | [38,|  -
     |  C2@gmail.com] |  1-1-1975] |  F]   |      |    N]        |  53]| 
 D   |  D@gmail.com   |  1-1-1980  |  M    | [D,  |    Y         |  43 |  -
     |                |            |       |  Q,  |              |     |      
     |                |            |       |  R,  |              |     |      
     |                |            |       |  T]  |              |     |   
 E   | [E@gmail.com,  |   2-6-1975 |  F    | [E,  |   [Y,        |  48 |    
     |  G@gmail.com]  |            |       |  G]  |    N]        |     |    
     |                |            |       |      |              |     |
```

And I want to split the rows in different rows getting something like that depending the values and the cases:

```
Name |      Mail      |  Birthday  | Genre | User | Subscription | Age | Comments
 A   | A@gmail.com    |  1-1-1990  |  M    |  Z   |    Y         |  33 |  -
 A2  | A@gmail.com    |  1-1-1998  |  F    |  A   |    Y         |  25 |  -
     |                |            |       |      |              |     |
 B   | B@gmail.com    |  13-2-1998 |  F    |  B   |    Y         |  24 |  -
     |                |            |       |      |              |     |
 C   | C@gmail.com    |  1-1-1985  |  M    |  C   |    Y         |  38 |  -
 C2  | C2@gmail.com   |  1-1-1975  |  F    |  C2  |    N         |  53 |  -
     |                |            |       |      |              |     |    
 D   | D@gmail.com    |  1-1-1980  |  M    |  D   |    Y         |  43 |  -
     |                |            |       |      |              |     |    
 E   | E@gmail.com    |  2-6-1975  |  F    |  E   |    Y         |  48 |  -  
 E2  | G@gmail.com    |  2-6-1975  |  F    |  G   |    N         |  48 |  -  
     |                |            |       |      |              |     |
```

Different possible cases:

- Remove dates like 1-1-1970 and 1-1-2000, and ages of this dates
- If only have list in user and not in the rest of columns remove all and use mail (without @)
- If only one user and 2 or more cases in other rows take the mail (without @) as user
- Split the rows with lists and if in a column there is not a list keep the same value in both rows

I don't know if it's possible i just took the data form a bad organized data base.

I got the first DataFrame using the function from [How can i combine and pull apart rows of a DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75069403/how-can-i-combine-and-pull-apart-rows-of-a-dataframe/75069537#75069537) answer.

I tried to split this rows with this function:

```
def split_list_cols(row):
    split_rows = []
    for col, val in row.items():
        if isinstance(val, list):
            for item in val:
                new_row = row.copy()
                new_row[col] = item
                split_rows.append(new_row)
            row[col] = None
    return split_rows
```

but did not work well.

From this dataframe

```
Name |      Mail      |  Birthday  | Genre | User | Subscription | Age | Comments
 E   | [E@gmail.com,  |   2-6-1975 |  F    | [E,  |   [Y,        |  48 |  -  
     |  G@gmail.com]  |            |       |  G]  |    N]        |     |    
     |                |            |       |      |              |     |
```

gives me:

```
Name |      Mail      |  Birthday  | Genre | User | Subscription | Age | Comments
 E   | E@gmail.com    |   2-6-1975 |  F    | [E,  |   [Y,        |  48 |   - 
     |                |            |       |  G]  |    N]        |     |    
 E   | G@gmail.com    |   2-6-1975 |  F    | [E,  |   [Y,        |  48 |   - 
     |                |            |       |  G]  |    N]        |     |    
 E   | None           |   2-6-1975 |  F    |  E   |   [Y,        |  48 |    
     |                |            |       |      |    N]        |     |     
 E   | None           |   2-6-1975 |  F    |  G   |   [Y,        |  48 |    
     |                |            |       |      |    N]        |     |    
 E   | None           |   2-6-1975 |  F    | None |    Y         |  48 |    
     |                |            |       |      |              |     |    
     |                |            |       |      |              |     | 
 E   | None           |   2-6-1975 |  F    | None |    N         |  48 |
```

and it should give:

```
 E   | E@gmail.com    |  2-6-1975  |  F    |  E   |    Y         |  48 |  -  
 E2  | G@gmail.com    |  2-6-1975  |  F    |  G   |    N         |  48 |  -  
     |                |            |       |      |              |     |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Different possible cases:

Its hard to understand all of the cases. But from what I understood I you could do this:

```
df = df.explode(["Birthday", "Genre", "User", "Subscription"])
df = df[(df["Birthday"].ne("1-1-1970")) & (df["Birthday"].ne("1-1-2000"))]
df = df.drop_duplicates(ignore_index=True)
df["Name"] = df["Name"] + df.groupby("Name").cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
df["User"] = df["User"] + df.groupby("User").cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
```